# Combining two FQL SELECT results into the same array

Tags: facebook-fql

I am running a Facebook FQL query to retrieve user information with the following:

```
    $fql    =   "SELECT uid, name, first_name, last_name, email, birthday FROM user where uid={$facebook_id}";
    $param  =   array(
        'method'     => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql,
        'callback'    => ''
    );

    $fqlResult    =   $facebook->api($param);

    $fb_username = facebook_connect($fqlResult[0]);
```

So far, so good ...everything works. But, I also need to run another SELECT query against another table to then retrieve the avatar:

```
    "SELECT url FROM profile_pic WHERE id={$facebook_id} AND width=250 AND height=250";
```

How do I join these 2 together so that I get a single `$fqlResult[0]['name']` or `$fqlResult[0]['url']`, etc ?

Right now, I only figured out a way to running to separate `$fql` and `$fql2` queries but then I can't manage to join the results so that they can be used together in the same array.

Thank you for any advice :)

Comment: if it is returning an `array` the try with `array_merge()` or `$array1 + $array2`

Answer (score 1):

OK, i thought you had imported the data from facebook in to a local database, but looking at your union answer it looks like you are talking directly to Facebook.

Have you looked in to multi query? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql, this might be a solution to your problem.

Else there is this thread on SO

[FQL Multiquery writing join queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222111/fql-multiquery-writing-join-queries)

Answer (score 0):

Use join

```
"SELECT *  FROM user u JOIN  profile_pic p ON u.uid = p.uid"
```

now attach your wheres and your columns, you select a column by using eg: p.url or u.name

Answer (score 0):

Try [UNION ALL](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union_all.php):

```
  $query = $fq1." UNION ALL ".$fq2;
```

Comment: This will not work since he will get a HUGE table with no relation to eachother. every row in $fql1 would be mached with EVERY row in $fql2, so if he has 10 rows in fql1 and 20 in fql2 he would end up with 200 rows of data.

Comment: Since he hasnt double entries it wouldnt just bring the urls with the others, but even this way i just notice the [0] after the fqresult. I havent notice that he wants to keep a relation between them. So union is useless indeed in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work indeed ...as FQL doesn't support UNION :(